# Jquery UI Layout plugin error in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I am just trying out the example shown in the jQuery UI Layout plugin documentation. I have downloaded the required libraries and copied and pasted the code under the "example" page in the documentation.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.6.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>               
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery.layout-latest.min.js"></script>          
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south">South</div>
<div class="ui-layout-east">East</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This shows a nice layout and resizing works but when I re size any of the panels I get a JavaScript alert that says: "/Inaccurate size after resizing [north pane]. See error console for details".

This error only appears in IE9, in Google Chrome resizing works fine without the alert.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or how to go about not showing that Alert? Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping the four panels in a `ui-layout-container` div and call `.layout()` on that.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I tried your suggestion, but then nothing happens (no panes are shown at all). Same happens in Chrome (nothing). I am assuming by a ui-layout-container you mean: <div id="container" class="ui-layout-container"> and then calling $('#container').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });

Comment: I think you're missing the `layoutSettings` object which should contain selectors for the east, west panels.. etc.  Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this? Then it would be easier for people to investigate.

Comment: Thanks Robin and apologies for the late reply. I am just putting our some other fires at the moment and do not yet know how to use jsfiddle. As soon as I get a moment I will try and get it up. Thanks again for taking the time to try and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what version of jquery UI Layout you used in the sample code. But I got the same error as you do when using the following version of the libs:
jquery-1.7.2.js
jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js
jquery.layout-latest.js (ver. 1.3.0 – rc30.6)

Changing from ver 1.3.0 rc 30.6 with jquery.layout-1.2.0.js makes your sample run in IE9. However, there seems to be a bug in the redrawing of the splitterbar when I run the sample; the North and West/Center splitterbars are thinner after first drag & drop.

[Downloads for jquery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/downloads.cfm)

...also I just found out that the demo site includes samples that yield the same error when run in IE9! - it seems they have a thing or two to solve for the lib to work in IE...

[Buggy demos in IE9](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm)

Comment: Thanks for the update Caad9 and apologies for my late reply. I am using jquery-1.6.3.min.js. I have bypassed the problem by just writing my own layout helper library, mainly because my implementations do not require a center panel.

Comment: I posted a comment on Jquery UI Layout forum regarding their demos not working properly. Got a reply & now a new version of the .js is out in ver 1.3.0 RC-30.61 that seemingly fixes the IE9 issue... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jquery-ui-layout